# Using css sprites in an image tag

Tags: asp.net, css, cross-browser, background-image, css-sprites

I have a sprite where there are all kings of logos in it. I want to get one specific so I'm using this **css**

```
.prog_logo { background-image:url('../../image/sprite_logo.png'); }
.prog_logo_prime { background-position:0px -81px; width:52px; height:51px; }
```

and in my **aspx** I create put an image

```
<asp:Image ID="imgLogo" CssClass="prog_logo prog_logo_prime" runat="server" />
```

### Problems

- At Opera

[image]
**Perfect.**

- At Chrome

[image]
**White border.**

- At IE 9

[image]
**The sprite appears with a white border as well.**

- At FF

<strike>The image just doesn't appear at all.</strike> **Check comments**

---

How can I fix this in all browsers?

Comment: adding `display:inline-block;` in the CSS I made it appears without any problem on FF. but this was my only progress so far.

Comment: Also, changing to `float:left` will work for FF. The problem is still IE and the borders

Answer (score 0):

How about adding border:none to the css?

```
.prog_logo { background-image:url('../../image/sprite_logo.png'); border:none; }
```